# How to remove character in specific rows in R?

Tags: r, split, dataframe

If specific value is in V1, I would like to remove it from V2 column in next rows.

Input:

```
         V1               V2
19 49426099      19 49469087
19 49469087      19 49426099
6 29910378       6 29910742 - 6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154 
6 29910742       6 29910378 - 6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154 
6 29911064       6 29910378 - 6 29910742 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154
```

I expect this result:

```
         V1               V2
19 49426099      19 49469087
19 49469087      
6 29910378       6 29910742 - 6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154 
6 29910742       6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154 
6 29911064       6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154
```

Comment: We can try `Map(function(x,y) paste(setdiff(x,y), collapse=" - "),  strsplit(df1$V2, " - "), df1$V1)`

Comment: This codes didn't work. I still have result same input

Comment: Is this a data frame and are these strings or strangely formatted numeric values?

Comment: Yes it is data frame and the mode of data is "list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example dataframe:

```
d = data.frame(V1 = c('19 49426099','19 49469087','6 29910378','6 29910742','6 29911064'), V2 = c('19 49469087','19 49426099','6 29910742 - 6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154','6 29910378 - 6 29911064 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154','6 29910378 - 6 29910742 - 6 29911086 - 6 29911092 - 6 29911154'))
d$V1 = as.character(d$V1)
d$V2 = as.character(d$V2)
```

And here's a solution:

```
r = sapply(0:(nrow(d) - 1), function(i){
gsub(pattern = paste(d[1:i, 'V1'], collapse = '|'),'', x = d[i+1, 'V2'])
})
r = gsub(pattern = ' -  - ', replacement = '', x = r) # remove the gaps where numbers were removed
r = gsub(pattern = '^ - ', replacement = '', x = r) # remove gaps at the beginning
r = gsub(pattern = ' - $', replacement = '', x = r) # in case you have gaps at the end
d$V2 = r
```